# Using forms that overwrite ONE mySQL table column and the rest of that row's data

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

**Desired behavior:** I have a form that is designed to take data and put it into a mySQL table. The desired outcome is to have users enter their data, and if one submission in a particular column is submitted, the new data for the entire row will overwrite the old data.

**Current behavior:** Currently, the form on the user's end is outputting a duplicate error.

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO mainclosings (library, reason,
closedate, opendate) VALUES ('Boonton', 'inclement weather. ', '2018-06-21',
'2018-06-16').Duplicate entry 'Boonton' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**Steps I have taken to remedy the problem:**

- Set the category `library` as a primary key (note: this is the column that, if it matches a submission in the column, should overwrite the remaining columns.)
- Remove the unique keys from the other columns.
- Used ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to tell the form to update upon duplicate submission.

My table is named `mainclosings`. Something tells me there's something wrong with this particular part of my code.

```
INSERT INTO `mainclosings` 
(`Library`, `Reason`, `CloseDate`, `OpenDate`)  
VALUES ('Library', 1, 3, 3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Reason` = 1, `CloseDate` = 3, `OpenDate` = 3
```

The part I am having difficulty with is that this is all based off of a form with user input. Therefore, any variable is unknown until the user submits the form.

The very last line of the code above, beginning with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` shows what columns are to be updated. I only want to update submissions where the `Library` column is identical. The rest of that particular row will update with new information.

Also, the form itself has a piece of mySQL in it that I want to verify isn't somehow 'butting heads' with the other code I am applying. This is below (perhaps something with the INSERT INTO statement?)

```
//Attempt to insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable (library, reason, closedate, opendate) VALUES 
('$library', '$reason', '$closedate', '$opendate')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    echo "<br><br>Thank you for submitting.";

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql." . mysqli_error($link);
}

//Close Connection
```

Comment: Sounds like you need an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Well, if your primary column is `library`, than the query with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause should work. Did you try that? What does it say?